# Google SERP ranks wrong URL for target keywords

Tags: seo, google-search, google-ranking

I have `[1] https://www.example.com/landing-1` ranking for "landing-1" keyword.

I have created `[2] https://www.example.com/landing-2 page` for "landing-2" keyword.

When I observed my rankings in google, the [2] page started ranking for "landing-1" keyword. How do I fix this?

Notes:

- Sitemap is created correctly to differentiate URLs for Google Bot, has been submitted and crawled successfully.
- On-page optimization with respect to keywords on both landing pages have been done
- This issue occurs frequently when trying to create sub-pages or power-pages linking to the target landing page.
- I have gone through this answer "[Google is indexing wrong page for search terms not on that page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95129/google-is-indexing-wrong-page-for-search-terms-not-on-that-page)", not helpful or relevant for my scenario.
- I am looking for any possible fixes other than above, if any to not let my rankings drop for the main page. (When the sub-pages or power pages are created, the ranking shifts from the main landing page to the newly created page for a long period of time, which affects the traffic, lead flow and conversion.)

Comment: Fix the keywords on the pages.

Comment: Yes it has been completed. Wonder why it is showing results for keywords not included in the page. We have even given a hyperlink for the main landing page with the root keyword.

Comment: Just because the other question doesn't have all the answers doesn't mean that it isn't a duplicate question.   You could create a bounty on the duplicate to encourage more answers.

Comment: So can I update the previous question with the current details and start a bounty? Talking about updating it with these details as the original question is too specific.

Comment: We get this question a lot.  I went through the search and found two more.

Comment: The answers seem to be question specific and do not have an generalized answer or a wiki. I'm running my last use case and if that works, will create a wiki answer for this when I get time. Many thanks for pointing out the previous questions.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The experiment I ran failed. I'm interested to start a bounty on the original question. If I start it and the original user is inactive, can you mark the correct answer? Also, I'd have to edit the question to reflect all scenarios correctly to get the right answer?